# ListView with dynamic raws and columns that stays propetinal aytomatically

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, panel

I am developing a WPF application.

have a list of user controls

```
   <Grid >
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                   MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                   ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Views:MyUserControl Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

And MyUserControl has another list of user controls "DetailUserControl":

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300"  d:DesignWidth="300" >

<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="45" />
        <RowDefinition  />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.RowSpan="2" >
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"   Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SummaryInnerFill}" >
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DetailUserControls}"  >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        </ItemsControl>

    </Border>

</Grid>
```

I used wrap panel to make all the usercontrols to be orderd from left to right one after the other.

I want the layout to be optimized and use as much as it can from the first line, and only then it will move to the second line.

here is an example (sorry for my drawing skills :) )

I have the following layout:

[image]

if I change the order inside the tiles I can have the following layout (that contains the same tiles but don't waste space an is much more organized):

[image]

Is there a  panel I can use that will take care of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Uniform Control Grid. You can specify Rows and Columns Properties. Controls are added to the grid in the order that they are declared.Its child controls are organised into a tabular structure of rows and columns. Unlike the Grid control, you don't have fine-grained control of the layout.

Example,

```
 <UniformGrid Name="uniformGrid1"
             Rows="2"
             Columns="3">
    <Button Content="blah"
             Margin="2" />
    <Button Content="blah1"
             Margin="2" />
    <Button Content="blah2"
            Margin="2" />
</UniformGrid>
```

[UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: But I don't know how many rows and columns I am going to need.